# Dropping root privileges

Tags: c, unix, root

I have a daemon which gets started as root (so it can bind to low ports). After initialisation I'd very much like to have it drop root privileges for safety reasons.

Can anyone point me at a *known correct* piece of code in C which will do this?

I've read the man pages, I've looked at various implementations of this in different applications, and they're all different, and some of them are really complex. This is security-related code, and I really don't want to reinvent the same mistakes that other people are making. What I'm looking for is a best practice, known good, portable library function that I can use in the knowledge that it's going to get it right. Does such a thing exist?

For reference: I'm starting as root; I need to change to run under a different uid and gid; I need to have the supplementary groups set up correctly; I don't need to change back to root privileges afterwards.

Comment: This varies quite a bit between unixes - are there any in particular ? If you need a "portable" solution, it's going to be messy, and you're best off grabbing e.g. the permanently_set_uid() function from OpenSSH - in the uidswap.c file

Comment: Maybe a better strategy, don't require root so it does not need to be dropped. Also see [Allow non-root process to bind to port 80 and 443?](https://superuser.com/q/710253/173513) A related topic is [Setuid Demystified](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/TEACHING/comp_sec_F04/downloads/setuid.pdf) bye Chen, Dean and Wagner. Different flavors of Unix have slightly different behaviors. Its another reason to punt and allow your unprivileged process to bind to the port.

Comment: Also see [Setuid Demystified](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~daw/papers/setuid-usenix02.pdf) on Usenix.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're looking for this article:

[POS36-C. Observe correct revocation order while relinquishing privileges](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/POS36-C.+Observe+correct+revocation+order+while+relinquishing+privileges)

Not sure how to best put some information there without duplicating the content of that page ...

Comment: (Very belated) Precisely what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: You should provide your code and explain it. There's a lot to explain.

Comment: Link above is dead. Here's a link to the Internet Archives's Way Back Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20201025080250/https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/POS36-C.+Observe+correct+revocation+order+while+relinquishing+privileges

Answer (score 51):

In order to drop all privileges (user and group), you need to drop the group before the user. Given that `userid` and `groupid` contains the IDs of the user and the group you want to drop to, and assuming that the effective IDs are also root, this is accomplished by calling [setuid()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setuid) and [setgid()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setgid):

```
if (getuid() == 0) {
    /* process is running as root, drop privileges */
    if (setgid(groupid) != 0)
        fatal("setgid: Unable to drop group privileges: %s", strerror(errno));
    if (setuid(userid) != 0)
        fatal("setuid: Unable to drop user privileges: %S", strerror(errno));
}
```

If you are paranoid, you can try to get your root privileges back, which should fail. If it doesn't fail, you bailout:

```
 if (setuid(0) != -1)
     fatal("ERROR: Managed to regain root privileges?");
```

Also, if you are still paranoid, you may want to [seteuid()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/seteuid) and [setegid()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setegid) too, but it shouldn't be necessary, since setuid() and setgid() already set all the IDs if the process is owned by root.

The supplementary group list is a problem, because there is no POSIX function to set supplementary groups (there is [getgroups()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getgroups), but no setgroups()). There is a BSD and Linux extension [setgroups()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setgroups) that you can use, it this concerns you.

You should also [`chdir("/")`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir) or to any other directory, so that the process doesn't remain in a root-owned directory.

Since your question is about Unix in general, this is the very general approach. Note that in Linux this is no longer the preferred approach. In current Linux versions, you should set the [`CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` capability](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities) on the executable, and run it as a normal user. No root access is needed.

Comment: You'd want to set the gid as well - and this might vary slightly across unixes regarding wether setuid/setgid actually messes with the real and saved id's as well

Comment: This does indeed need to be a portable solution, so no Linux capability fu allowed, I'm afraid. And I have indeed tried the simple approach with setuid() and setgid(); it doesn't set the groups correctly (and if you don't call setgroups(), apparently you can end up still being a member of some of root's groups!).

Comment: @nos Thanks. Expanded to cover groups. If the process is owned by root (as the OP mentioned) or if it is setuid-root, then setuid() and setgid() already set all IDs (real, effective and saved). This is in the specification. Otherwise, the implementation would not be POSIX-conforming.

Comment: If setuid()/setgid() set all the IDs, why then do most implementations I've seen (including the OpenSSH one that nos linked to) call seteuid()/setegid() as well? Why does it prefer to use setresuid() and setreuid() rather than basic setuid()?

Comment: @David I do not know. Perhaps for compatibility with some broken Unix implementation, for safety, etc. Perhaps because it considers process not running as root (which is not your case). You can check the POSIX standard about the implementation of setuid(), it is clear about the semantics of setuid(): http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/setuid.html . You asked for a portable solution, setresuid() and setreuid() are not portable.

Comment: You can use `initgroups(3)` to reset the supplementary groups, it's portable enough (at least BSD and GNU libc have it).

Comment: Always clear the supplemental groups as well. initgroups exists on AIX, Solaris, HP-UX, FreeBSD, Darwin, Linux, and probably others. Include it so the build fails if it can't be found. Not dropping all groups can lead to serious system compromise and CVEs. I don't think chdir has any security implications at all, does it?

Comment: Note on setgroups: POSIX isn't a full list of all possible operating system functions, but rather is the lowest common denominator. So it's not terribly surprising if you ever want to use a piece of functionality that's missing from POSIX, and have to use an OS-specific function.

Answer (score 3):

This was what I could do best:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE  // for secure_getenv()


int drop_root_privileges(void) {  // returns 0 on success and -1 on failure
    gid_t gid;
    uid_t uid;

    // no need to "drop" the privileges that you don't have in the first place!
    if (getuid() != 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    // when your program is invoked with sudo, getuid() will return 0 and you
    // won't be able to drop your privileges
    if ((uid = getuid()) == 0) {
        const char *sudo_uid = secure_getenv("SUDO_UID");
        if (sudo_uid == NULL) {
            printf("environment variable `SUDO_UID` not found\n");
            return -1;
        }
        errno = 0;
        uid = (uid_t) strtoll(sudo_uid, NULL, 10);
        if (errno != 0) {
            perror("under-/over-flow in converting `SUDO_UID` to integer");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    // again, in case your program is invoked using sudo
    if ((gid = getgid()) == 0) {
        const char *sudo_gid = secure_getenv("SUDO_GID");
        if (sudo_gid == NULL) {
            printf("environment variable `SUDO_GID` not found\n");
            return -1;
        }
        errno = 0;
        gid = (gid_t) strtoll(sudo_gid, NULL, 10);
        if (errno != 0) {
            perror("under-/over-flow in converting `SUDO_GID` to integer");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    if (setgid(gid) != 0) {
        perror("setgid");
        return -1;
    }
    if (setuid(uid) != 0) {
        perror("setgid");
        return -1;    
    }

    // change your directory to somewhere else, just in case if you are in a
    // root-owned one (e.g. /root)
    if (chdir("/") != 0) {
        perror("chdir");
        return -1;
    }

    // check if we successfully dropped the root privileges
    if (setuid(0) == 0 || seteuid(0) == 0) {
        printf("could not drop root privileges!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the first check should call `geteuid()` since `getuid()` returns the real uid.