# Give up root privilegies?

Tags: c++, root

I have a program which runs a bunch of tasks as root at launch. After that it needs to drop to a different user. How can that be done?

And just wondering, is it possible to reacquire root without relaunching the program?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357737/dropping-root-privileges (the answer is mostly language-independent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is to use the [`setuid()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setuid.html) function.

It is not possible to reacquire root privileges after switching to a non-root user.

Comment: "It is not possible to reacquire root privileges after switching to a non-root user." As a matter of fact, this is *the whole point* of dropping superuser privs. You want to limit the impact of any security holes in your program. If you could re-escalate, so could any exploit targeting your program...

Comment: @sleske: actually, if your effective UID is not root, and the implementation supports _POSIX_SAVED_IDS, you can regain the original effective UID.