# How to drop privilege temporarily from root?

Tags: c, linux

I am developing a daemon running as root, but need to call an API with the user, I checked the API codes, it uses `getuid()` to get the user.

If root user drops privilege by `setuid()` , it can't be restored to root. If calling seteuid(), the API will still do something as user `uid=0`.

I think fork before accessing API and setuid in the child process should work, but even if COW , it will cost much if calling API many times. Is it possible to solve the problem except using process pool?

Comment: Also see [Setuid Demystified](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~daw/papers/setuid-usenix02.pdf) on Usenix, [Dropping root privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3357737/608639) and [Give up root privilegies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3436099/608639)

Answer (score 8):

Yes! Create a single process to call the API with the appropriate UID and communicate with the rest of the program through a Pipe, a UNIX domain socket or (*shared memory*)<sup>1</sup>.

I mean, fork only once and keep the privileged user running another process. Then create communication between the two if needed and as needed. Also, you might want to consider using [*dbus*](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/) since it also integrates perfectly with [systemd](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) and on modern linux you want your daemon to interact nicely with both.

**Note**: I am by no means an expert on the subject, but this is a simple idea that seems clear to me. You don't need to create a process for every call to the API. This is a good example of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info), the real problem that you want to solve, has nothing to do with avoiding to `fork()` multiple times because the idea of doing that is the wrong solution. You only need to `fork()` once, drop privileges and stay there without privileges, communicating with the parent process if/as needed.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Any IPC mechanism that works for you.</sub>

Comment: This is an effective approach, except for *dbus*. Use a [socket pair](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socketpair.2.html) if possible, so that the connection is secure from third parties. (The original process still has root privileges, and we do not want it to be exploitable by flooding or faked messages.) I have used this personally quite a few times, but more importantly, so have others. Most widely used examples are probably Apache [mod_cgid](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_cgid.html) and [mod_fcgid](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/) modules.

Comment: Why don't use another machine also, to help in the work?  Is there any solution that consumes more resources than yours?  A simple call to `seteuid(2)` should allow to switch ids between the `suid` user id and the `real` user id.  And this predates from UNIX v7.

Comment: If the API has any security concerns about it, I would advise against communication via shared memory. The risk of an attacker triggering undefined behavior in the privileged process via garbage data in the shared memory region is much more severe than via a message sent through a pipe. With the shared memory region, you have fully asynchronous access of the two processes to the shared region, with a pipe, you can be certain that the child won't change the data once you received it in the parent. Thus the parent can validate the data at leisure before actually acting on it.

Comment: @cmaster, please, don't be so critic and give a solution... Publish the right answer to the problem.  I only read your critics, but no affordable solution has been posted by you.  Please, go ahead and give a complete, working solution to the asker. This is not a forum to put opinions, just to solve people problems.

Comment: @LuisColorado Well, this answer *is* a good solution, and it includes the best solution that I see to the problem, so no answer from me. I was merely commenting here that not all methods of IPC to implement this solution are equally good: IPC via shared memory is less secure than IPC via pipes, because the former allows more attack surface from the unprivileged process to the privileged one.

Answer (score 4):

Just call `seteuid(2)` to do the appropiate unprivileged stuff.  `seteuid(2)` allows to switch between the *real*(or saved) user id (the one that launches the suid program or `root` in your case) and *the suid* user id (the one the suid program belongs to)  so there should be no problem to regain privileged user id afterwards (as the saved user id is `root`, you don't have any issue to switch to it again and again).

If you change uids with `setuid(2)` you'll change **all** (effective, saved and real uids) and this is only allowed to the root user (or a program setuid root, and there's no way back then).

Look at the next example:

## File pru49015.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int opt, suid = getuid(), /* this is the saved uid */
        uid = 0;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "i:")) != EOF) {
        switch (opt) {
        case 'i': uid = atoi(optarg); break;
        }
    }
    /* execute this program with root privileges, like setuid root, for example */
    printf("real uid=%d; effective uid=%d\n", getuid(), geteuid());
    seteuid(uid);  /* change to the non-privileged id configured */
    printf("real uid=%d; effective uid=%d\n", getuid(), geteuid());
    seteuid(suid); /* return back to saved uid */
    printf("real uid=%d; effective uid=%d\n", getuid(), geteuid());
}
```

You will get an output like this:

```
$ pru49015 -i 37
real uid=502; effective uid=0
real uid=502; effective uid=37
real uid=502; effective uid=502
```

when used as a setuid-root program

If you use it as root, you'll get the following output:

```
$ sudo pru$$ -i 37
real uid=0; effective uid=0
real uid=0; effective uid=37
real uid=0; effective uid=0
```

The mechanism is that you are allowed on a setuid- program to switch between the user you are (let's call it the *saved user id*) and the user the program runs setuid to (the called *effective user id* or *suid* user) as many times as you want.

Comment: I think, it should be noted that this approach is not nearly as secure as the fork-setuid-communicate approach: If an attacker takes over your process, it immediately has access to root privileges (via a single additional call to `seteuid()`). With the fork-setuid-communicate approach, an attacker only gains access to the lower privileges, it needs to additionally hack the parent process still running as root to actually gain root privileges. I believe this is the reason why `setuid()` does not allow a process to get back to elevated privileges.

Comment: @cmaster, Yes, but if the attacker has access to the process, it can get access before it goes to unprivileged status... and then it has privileged access also.  Are you telling me that your `fork-seuid-communicate` approach is more secure than the `seteuid(2)` syscall?  Have you found any vulnerability on the `seteuid(2)` call?  Why then is it implemented in all unix varieties since UNIX v7 and nobody has noticed?  By the way, if you write all those programs, why do you think the attacker is not going to select the most vulnerable point (in this case, this *overloaded* privileged process)

Comment: @cmaster, if your attacker only gets access to the unprivileged process the problem is that your attacker has selected the wrong process to attack.  For the kind of attack you are describing, you have to get access to some vulnerability that allows you to place your code in the process virtual space.  That means that the vulnerability must be in the privileged process.  But in your scenario, the privileged process also exists, and is equally vulnerable (but responsible of many more resources --- communications, sockets, clients) to this kind of attacks.

Comment: "but if the attacker has access to the process, it can get access before it goes to unprivileged status..." Only if you do the privilege dropping wrong. It all depends on the *time* that a successful attack on the process is possible. Usually, the goal of dropping privileges is to do the stuff that could possibly contain security vulnerabilities only *after* privileges have been dropped, depriving the attacker exploiting those vulnerabilities of the elevated privileges. The privileged part should be as small as possible to expose as little attack surface as possible.

Comment: i'm afraid that if you make things wrong... you are vulnerable.  `seteuid(2)` syscal is there to be used... not to be feared.  Please, be pragmatic, don't make users fear making syscalls.  The majority of vulnerabilities are not in the system calls, but in the use of libraries poorly implemented or not tested enough.  You cannot tell me that using a system call is more dangeours that including hundreds of libraries that alleviate the problem... they don't alleviate the security problem... they just augment the probabilities of finding a vulnerability.

Comment: I don't know why I recommended `setreuid()` when `seteuid()` is simpler and does the Right Thing in the common use case!  +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the former effective uid in the *saved UID* of the process:

```
uid_t real = getuid();
uid_t privileged = geteuid();
setresuid(real, real, privileged);
do_API_call(); // API's getuid() call now returns real
setresuid(real, privileged, -1); // allowed, since saved==privileged
```

There's a corresponding `setresgid` to use saved GIDs, too.

---

Note that this answer is specific to Linux (as per question tags).  A similar call exists on HP-UX and some BSD systems, but I haven't checked that the semantics are identical.

---

Actually, on further reading `setreuid()` should be sufficient (and POSIX-conformant).  `setuid()` says:

> If the effective UID of the caller is root (more precisely: if the caller has the `CAP_SETUID` capability), the real UID and saved set-user-ID are also
>          set.

and

> If  the  user  is root or the program is set-user-ID-root, special care must be taken.  The `setuid()` function checks the effective user ID of the caller and if it is the superuser, all process-related user ID's are
>          set to `uid`.  After this has occurred, it is impossible for the program to regain root privileges.

but there is no such statement for `setreuid()`.

Comment: Actually, since the saved UID is initialized to the effective UID following `exec()`, you should be able to use `seteuid()` as in [Luis's answer](/a/39263593), which leaves the saved UID alone, for you to return to).

Answer (score -1):

From [here](http://etutorials.org/Programming/secure+programming/Chapter+1.+Safe+Initialization/1.3+Dropping+Privileges+in+setuid+Programs/):

> Normally when a process is executed, the effective, real, and saved user and group IDs are all set to the real user and group ID of the process's parent, respectively. However, when the setuid bit is set on an executable, the effective and saved user IDs are set to the user ID that owns the file.