# Switch user at run time when program runs as root

Tags: c++, linux

If some c++ program runs as root and i want to execute some of the commands with different user and read the output of that command and again switch back to root user so can someone guide me how to achieve that in linux OS & c++ ?

Below is the reference code i wrote. Can someone guide me which is correct or not ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

std::wstring PopenRead(const std::wstring &cmd)
{
    std::wstring res;
    std::string s_cmd(cmd.begin(), cmd.end());
    FILE *f = popen((const char *)s_cmd.c_str(), "r");

    if (f)
    {
            char buffer[1024];
            int cnt;
            int rc;

            while ((cnt = fread(buffer, 1, 1024, f)) > 0)
            {
                    buffer[cnt] = 0;
                    std::string s_val = std::string(buffer);
                    std::wstring wsTmp(s_val.begin(), s_val.end());
                    res += wsTmp;
            }

            rc = pclose(f);
            std::wcout << "Output is: " << res << std::endl;

            return res;
    }
    return L"";
}

int main()
{
    std::wstring command = L"su test_user -c 'ls -ltr /home/test_user'";
    std::wstring exec_res = PopenRead(command);    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add linux commands you tried and C++ code you wrote inside the question of the body?

Comment: And don't use the C tag for C++ questions.

Comment: There are two separate questions here: how to drop to non-root for an execution of program, and how to capture the output of a program. And both very likely have been answered already!

Comment: Easiest is to switch user using `su -c` for the executed program.

Comment: Check out the man page for `seteuid()` -- it is specifically designed to allow a program running as root to execute as a non-root user, and then switch back to root against afterwards.

Comment: @YatShah, Added the code. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Also see [Setuid Demystified](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~daw/papers/setuid-usenix02.pdf), [Dropping root privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3357737/608639), [Give up root privilegies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3436099/608639) and [How to drop privilege temporarily from root?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39202761/608639)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do it using `popen` and `sudo` command as I'm using `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`

Please find below code in C++

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <array>

int main()
{
   //To switch user as user
   std::string switch_user_command("echo 'userpassword' | sudo -u user 2>&1");

   std::array<char, 128> buffer;
   std::string result;

   std::cout << "Opening reading pipe" << std::endl;
   FILE* pipe;
   pipe  = popen(switch_user_command.c_str(), "r");
   if (!pipe)
   {
      std::cerr << "Couldn't start command." << std::endl;
      return 0;
   }
    while (fgets(buffer.data(), 128, pipe) != NULL) {
       //std::cout << "Reading..." << std::endl;
       result += buffer.data();
   }
   auto returnCode1 = pclose(pipe);

   std::cout << result << std::endl;
   std::cout << returnCode1 << std::endl;

   result.clear();
   //To run ls command
   std::string command("ls 2>&1");
   pipe = popen(command.c_str(), "r");
   if (!pipe)
   {
       std::cerr << "Couldn't start command." << std::endl;
       return 0;
   }
   while (fgets(buffer.data(), 128, pipe) != NULL) {
       //std::cout << "Reading..." << std::endl;
       result += buffer.data();
   }
   auto returnCode2 = pclose(pipe);

   std::cout << result << std::endl;
   std::cout << returnCode2 << std::endl;

   //To run command  as root/sudo
   result.clear();
   std::cout << "Trying to run ls as sudo .. " << std::endl;
   std::string switch_root_command("echo 'sudopassword' | sudo -S ls 2>&1");

   pipe = popen(switch_root_command.c_str(), "r");
   if (!pipe)
   {
       std::cerr << "Couldn't start command." << std::endl;
       return 0;
   }
   while (fgets(buffer.data(), 128, pipe) != NULL) {
      //std::cout << "Reading..." << std::endl;
      result += buffer.data();
   }
   auto returnCode3 = pclose(pipe);

   std::cout << result << std::endl;
   std::cout << returnCode3 << std::endl;

  return 0;
  }
```

Please use below command to compile in `g++`

> g++ prog.cpp -o prog -std=c++11

This produces below output (as I don't have any 'user' account)

```
Opening reading pipe
sudo: unknown user: user
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

256
1.cpp
2
2.cpp

0
Trying to run ls as sudo ..
1.cpp
2
2.cpp
0
abhi

0
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: This will run but it will be security risk  as we are exposing password here. User can steal the password from "ps" command.

Comment: Thanks, @Neel for bringing this out. We can have a password in the library in an encrypted format. Which can be used to prepare the command at run-time.