# Reducing privileges of a process on Unix or Gnu/Linux

Tags: linux, security, unix

I am writing a program, and want it to run with reduced privileges. I know as root I can do this, but what about as a normal user. Can I set the user to nobody, without first setting it to root?

Comment: Why do you ask? Explain much more what is your program, and what exactly it is doing...

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357737/dropping-root-privileges

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot change the user of a process to `nobody` without root permission.

The relevant syscalls are [setuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html), [seteuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/seteuid.2.html), [setresuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setresuid.2.html) ...

<sup>(There might be perhaps a Linux-specific way of restricting new file operations on a process, but I can't recall the details)</sup>

See also [SE-Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), [Setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid), [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html), [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) and read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) ...

Comment: This is certainly true for linux, but solaris & Mac OS X have even more fine grained privileges such as file access, network access, exec, fork

Comment: @Petesh Linux has the concept of the file system user ID, normally equal to the effective user ID.  The setuid() call also sets the file system user ID of the calling process.  See setfsuid(2) http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setfsuid.2.html .

Comment: @richard I'm well aware of it, but it's not particularly fine-grained. It's at the same level as `setuid` et al. As an ordinary user, you can remove permissions on your process using the mechanisms provided in Solaris/Mac OS X, which is IMHO significantly more powerful. The tags contained `unix` so I added this as a mention

Comment: @Petesh sound interesting, can you include a bit more info? Api calls etc.

Comment: The [Solaris page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1456/privtask-1.html) gives a good overview of privileges, but you would need to dig through the man pages for API calls. The documentation of the [Mac OS X sandbox](http://reverse.put.as/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Apple-Sandbox-Guide-v1.0.pdf) is best described by other people (apple has gone the simple route for this).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to set root permission, but you must start the program as either a root user or another admin user.

Comment: Did you just say, “The process does not have to be root, but it does have to be root.”?