# How to block Particular Commands in Linux for Specific user?

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, centos, rhel

Suppose i create a new user TEST in ubuntu and i need to block all commands except cp,ssh,exit.Please help me.i am new to linux.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Is it serious?

Comment: If you are really newbie in Linux, and you need a serious thing, I would recommend to learn much more about Linux before deploying your solution. So I would suggest to give up, or trust somehow your users.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, consider using some *restricted shell* like [rbash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html) which you might set up as the user's login & ssh shell (use `chsh` and/or configure his/her's `~/.ssh/config`); of course set up the `PATH` appropriately, it might contain a single `~/bin/` directory containing symlinks to `/bin/cp`, `/usr/bin/ssh`, etc. You might want to make `~/bin/` not owned and not writable by the user.

<sup>Be careful: if your user is more experimented than you are, you might leave some holes that he/she would be able to exploit. Make it also a social/contractual issue, by at least *explicitly* forbidding (in words) things.</sup>

You might also want to learn more about [*chroot*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) and/or [*setuid*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid); see also the references in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18833155/841108).

Notice that if your user gets `ssh`, he is likely to get `scp` and be able to hack his account (e.g. by adding executable files into his `~/bin/` ....)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a new group in which you set all the commands you want to use and add your TEST user to this group.

Comment: If u dont mind can you please explain me in detail?

Comment: @user3226587: it is not worth the effort. Unless you know a lot more about Linux you are sure to make security mistakes.

Comment: Basile is right it's not the easyest way. Go see this topic, it's very close to your situation : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498667/how-to-limit-user-commands-in-linux