# how kube-apiserver worked on binding 443 port using non-root?

Tags: kubernetes

I noticed that installed kube-apiserver prog can start on port 443 (<1024) using non-root user 'kube'.

But I can't find any clue how kube-apiserver prog works. Any help? I have the problem of binding port 443 when upgrade kube-apiserver by cp.

Also I know linux capabilities (CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE Bind a socket to Internet domain privileged ports (port numbers less than 1024).) such as:

```
setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /path/to/program.
```

But I find nothing searching keyword "setcap" from the whole project.

Comment: How did you install Kubernetes?

Comment: yum install kubernets and k8s ansible script install are both ok.

Comment: IMO this isn't handled by Kubernetes itself. Usually the apiserver runs as a pod with [`hostNetwork` enabled](http://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1/definitions/#_v1_podspec). Probably this is handled by the `systemd` unit files which are provided by the RPM package maintainer. In the many cases using ports below `1024` as non-root is implemented by [dropping root privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357737/dropping-root-privileges) after starting.

Comment: Thanks. At first I installed `kubernetes 1.2.1` by using ansbile script, `kube-apiserver 1.2.1` can work well on port 443.  Then I installed `kubernetes 1.2.3` on another cluster by using ansbile script, `kube-apiserver 1.2.3` can work well on port 443.  But only after  the `kube-apiserver 1.2.1` replaced by kube-apiserver v1.2.3 binary without change any config file or service file, `kube-apiserver v1.2.3` can't worked on 443 port.  Finally, I run `setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' kube-apiserver(v1.2.3)` , it can work on port 443 now. I changed nothing to  `systemed`  file.

Comment: Then the capability change was maybe done by the install script of the RPM package.

Comment: Got it. [ansible/roles/master/tasks/main.yml](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/ansible/roles/master/tasks/main.yml)  `- name: add cap_net_bind_service to kube-apiserver
  capabilities: path=/usr/bin/kube-apiserver capability=cap_net_bind_service=ep state=present
  when: not is_atomic and not is_coreos and not ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu' and not ansible_distribution_major_version|int < 15`