Set program permissions at runtime
I am trying to use a linux kernel module to do some hardware control on my raspberry pi. It's fairly trivial user-level code, but implementing some of the functionality as a kernel module is a necessary academic exercise. The kernel module sends a SIGIO signal to the user-level code on button press, which is output to a speaker connected to a breadboard using aplay. aplay connects to a pulseaudio server which (rightly) refuses to connect as root. How do I tell my program that I want to run this line of code as a regular user?
This is a rough skeleton based on the user-level code, not the kernel module.
/* various includes */

void main() {
    // stuff that requires sudo perms
    fd = open("/dev/manager", O_WRONLY);
    
    /* setup signal_handler() to handle signal from fd [omitted] */

    close(fd);
}

void signal_handler(int signo) {
    // None of this needs to be run with sudo privilege, and malfunctions if so
    setgid(1000); setuid(1000);        // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357737/dropping-root-privileges
    setenv("HOME", "/home/raspi", 1);  // aplay uses $HOME, which was /root and inaccessible

    /* generate output.wav [omitted] */
    system("aplay /path/to/file/output.wav");
}

Here's a minimal compilable version of some sandbox code so that you can better reproduce the issue yourselves. It plays when run as a regular user, but not as sudo. If I can run the below as sudo, fixing the above code should become straightforward.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main() {
    setgid(1000);
    setuid(1000);
    setenv("HOME", "/home/raspi", 1);
    system("aplay /path/to/file/output.wav");
}

I'm not even attached at the hip to aplay. If someone can give me any minimal working example of audio playing from a C program when run as sudo using whatever audio utility you have on hand, I'd love to see it.
Related Questions:
[1] Dropping root privileges - This almost answers my question. This should answer my question. It just didn't actually work when I tried it.
[2] sudo permission problems in c program - I am aware of what needs sudo and what doesn't need sudo here. What I'm unclear on is how to switch from one to the other at runtime.

You should add some error checking, so you can see what actually fails.

You may also need to set the PULSE_SERVER and PULSE_COOKIE environment variables, depending on your system.

Oh, I wasn't aware of the PULSE_SERVER and PULSE_COOKIE environment variables! Where are they documented? That seems fairly promising, though pulseaudio is pretty strict about permissions so I'm not confident that will work. I did however do a bunch of error checking and narrowing down the issue before posting. I just posted a stripped-down minimal example to avoid clutter. Permissions certainly are an issue with my configuration, even if they may not be the only one.

pulseaudio(1)

You could also try using groups instead of running your program as root (which is a better practice anyway). For example, create a manager group, set /dev/manager to belong to that group and set permissions to 660 (you can write an udev rule so you don't have to set the group every time). Then run your program with sudo -g manager ....

Can you try system("sudo -u pi aplay /path/to/file/output.wav"); ?

@Philippe: Substituting an appropriate username, that did not work. Same issue as running it as sudo without the -u flag.
@LHLaurini: I tried to follow your instructions but I'm not sure I did it right. My exact steps were: sudo groupadd bookreader (different name to keep myself from being confused about other managers not written by me). Next was sudo usermod -a -G bookreader raspi to give my account group permissions. Then sudo mknod /dev/manager c 61 0 so that there would be a target for sudo chgrp bookreader /dev/manager and sudo chmod 664 /dev/manager. [continued]

I inserted the kernel module with sudo insmod manager.ko, and then started my user level code with sudo -g bookreader ./book_reader. Unfortunately, the behavior was exactly the same as running it without the -g flag. There was no audio output. Running it as ./book_reader (without sudo) showed a failed to open device: Permission denied error.

While you need sudo to do things like insmod/modprobe, you don't need it to invoke your program ... AFAICT, the only reason you need sudo is because your program opens /dev/manager. Since /dev/manager is strictly for your device driver, who says that it must be owned by root and/or have [only] 600 permissions? If you do either: chown raspi: /dev/manager or chmod 666 /dev/manager, then you do not need to run your program as root. Thus, aplay will be run as a non-root user. What's the harm in any user opening the device and/or playing content?

@CraigEstey sudo chmod 666 /dev/manager did the trick! I'm crying tears of joy thank you so much! Do you want to make an answer post for this?

The notable difference between this approach and the prior one is that I did not run ./book_reader with sudo -g

Prefaced by the top comments ...

@CraigEstey sudo chmod 666 /dev/manager did the trick! I'm crying tears of joy thank you so much! Do you want to make an answer post for this? –
PR4v1

While we need sudo to do things like insmod/modprobe, we don't need it to invoke your program.

The only reason we need sudo is because your program opens /dev/manager. It is [probably] owned by root and has permission of (e.g.) 600 or 644.
Since /dev/manager is strictly for your device driver, we can set the ownership and/or permissions to any values we want.
There's little harm to having the device file be world writable. That is, we do want any user to be able to play audio, don't we?

If we do either of the following your program does not need to run as root:

chown raspi: /dev/manager
chmod 666 /dev/manager (preferred).

Thus, aplay will be run as a non-root user (and it will no longer complain about being root).
